# Responsive conditional Link / Button with PHP and maybe JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have the following code and I've been trying to get a multipurpose use out of this button/link.

If no items are picked, I need it to be a link with static text to the items and it has to utilize the page-scroll class (its an animated scroll to the section then the link stays highlighted while you're in that section) The page scroll only seems to work when in an < li > element.

Once an item is picked I want the link to change to a button (or enlighten me, if a link can do what I need) that shows the number of items picked and show loading text while new items are clicked. The button also drops down to show picked items.

I've tried it every which way, using only buttons, or only links, but I can only get one of the features to work at a time - either the drop down item/loading feature, or the scroll/highlight feature.
I'm think JQuery will help me switch between the link / button. Please help.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <?php if ($items) { ?>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle"> 
    <span id="results"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></button>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#itemlist">Item List</a></li> 
    <?php } ?>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
...
</ul>
</div>
```

This was my other version, but this doesn't give me the animated scrolling or highlight feature, it gives me the static text first, then changes to loading and counts, but if items are removed, it does not revert back to static text, just shows zero items (zero items should = static text):

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" 
<?php if ($items) { ?>
class="dropdown-toggle"><span id="results"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span> 
<?php } else { ?>
<a class="page-scroll" href="#itemlist">Item List</a> 
<?php } ?>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things, **keep it simple** and **independent** from each other. You don't always have to use the if-else all the time.

Looking at your code i am assuming that you are using [Bootstrap Dropdown](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp) and [Page Scroll](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/)

So you have 2 things going on:

1. Display **Link** for scrolling when there are **no items**.
2. Display **Item Drop down** when there are **items**.

Simplest way to do this is divide and rule, lets handle point 1 first:

**1. Display Link for scrolling when there are no items.**

```
<!-- If no items then show scroll link -->
<? if ( empty($items) ): ?>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#itemlist">Item List</a> 
<? endif; ?>
<!-- end -->
```

This should definitely work without `li` as it has nothing to do with `li` it is just linked with the section id. So somewhere down there you will have something like `<section id="itemlist"` where it will take you.

**2. Display Item Drop downs when there are items.**

Now, if you use the right hierarchy of classes as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp). Then this should work as well. Do not try to mix classes of two different components:

```
<!-- If items then show dropdown -->
<? if ( !empty($items) ): ?>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button 
        data-toggle="dropdown" 
        data-loading-text="<?=$text_loading;?>"
        class="dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
    >            
        <span id="results"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        ...
    </ul>
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```

Combining both codes, it should look like this:

```
<!-- If no items then show scroll link -->
<? if ( empty($items) ): ?>
    <a class="page-scroll" href="#itemlist">Item List</a> 
<? endif; ?>
<!-- end -->

<!-- If items then show dropdown -->
<? if ( !empty($items) ): ?>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button 
        data-toggle="dropdown" 
        data-loading-text="<?=$text_loading;?>"
        class="dropdown-toggle"
        type="button"
    >            
        <span id="results"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        ...
    </ul>
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```